# LibGDX My font doesn't work

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to change my font to a custom one from the web and I downloaded Cool Crayon from this site:
https://www.dafont.com/dk-cool-crayon.font
I got 2 files named Bitmap_0.tga and Bitmap.fnt

I tried to implement it to my code from my knowledge and a bit googling.

So far I have done this:

```
private Skin skin;


Skin font = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("font/Bitmap.fnt"));

behindTable = new Table(font);
table = new Table(font);

Label heading = new Label(QuizMain.TITLE, font);
TextButton buttonMap = new TextButton("Map", font);

table.add(heading).spaceBottom(100).row();        
table.add(buttonMap).spaceLeft(15);
```

At first I thought It would work but I keep getting errors and I can't understand how to move forward or if something I have written is wrong.

My logcat

```
  com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: font/Bitmap.fnt
```

ps. I know my table and all kind of "behind the scene" stuff works :)

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want but when I used custom fonts in libgdx I had to use Hiero. I can't remember well but I'll leave you a link here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero

Comment: I don't think LibGDX supports tga image files. Convert it to PNG in a paint program like Gimp or Photoshop.

Comment: As @Juan said it, you need to use Hiero to convert a font to a glyph that Gdx can use. I don't remember if HIero support OTF files but i'm sure it supports TTF files, read this https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero

Answer (score 0):

Your fault is here:

```
Skin font = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("font/Bitmap.fnt"));
```

You try to generate a Skin out of a font file. [Click here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin) to see how skins work.

For creating a BitmapFont out of a .fnt file you had to use something similar to this:

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/Bitmap.fnt"));
```